# Querying COSMOS DB graph vertices via REST

Tags: rest, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Is it possible to use REST services to access vertices in a Cosmos DB graph database?  That is, are there REST calls to run Gremlin-like queries?

The "Azure REST API reference", learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/ has examples such as how to get the graphs in the DB
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db-resource-provider/2021-03-15/gremlinresources/getgremlingraph
but not how to access the vertices in the graph.

I can find lots of example of how to run gremlin queries in code (such as using java) but not examples using REST.

I have found example where you write and deploy a function in Cosmos that parses a REST call into Gremlin queries, but I was looking for feature that are part of Cosmos.

Thank for any help

Answer (score 0):

Yes that rest api you're pointing to you in your question is the resource provider or management api.

There are a couple of rest clients written in python that you can find on the [Apache Tinkerpop](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/) site. Just scroll down until you see Language Drivers.